# Elastic Search "must" in array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm a newbie with Elastic Search.

I've got the next object indexed in elasticsearch:

```
                "doc": [
                    {
                        "partes": [
                            {
                                "algo": [
                                    {
                                        "Category": "Therapeutic or Preventive Procedure",
                                        "Neg": "false",
                                        "CandidatePreferred": "Obstetric Surgical Procedures",
                                        "CandidateScore": "1000",
                                        "CandidateMatched": "Obstetric Surgical",
                                        "Phrase": "OBSTETRIC SURGICAL",
                                        "CUI": "C0038906"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "partes": [
                            {
                                "algo": [
                                    {
                                        "Category": "Intellectual Product",
                                        "Neg": "false",
                                        "CandidatePreferred": "Given name",
                                        "CandidateScore": "790",
                                        "CandidateMatched": "given",
                                        "Phrase": "given of discharge",
                                        "CUI": "C3244317"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Category": "Body Substance",
                                        "Neg": "false",
                                        "CandidatePreferred": "Discharge, body substance",
                                        "CandidateScore": "790",
                                        "CandidateMatched": "Discharge",
                                        "Phrase": "given of discharge",
                                        "CUI": "C2926602"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "algo": [
                                    {
                                        "Category": "Health Care Activity",
                                        "Neg": "false",
                                        "CandidatePreferred": "Patient Discharge",
                                        "CandidateScore": "790",
                                        "CandidateMatched": "Discharge",
                                        "Phrase": "given of discharge",
                                        "CUI": "C0030685"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Category": "Intellectual Product",
                                        "Neg": "false",
                                        "CandidatePreferred": "Given name",
                                        "CandidateScore": "790",
                                        "CandidateMatched": "given",
                                        "Phrase": "given of discharge",
                                        "CUI": "C3244317"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

My objective is get the elements where i have two CUIs in the same element *algo*, i.e. there is an **algo** in the **doc** who have both CUI's: *C3244317* and *C2926602*.

I'm trying to make the next search:

```
{
    "query": {        
        "nested": {
            "path": "doc",
            "query": {
                "nested":{
                    "path":"doc.partes",
                    "query": {
                        "nested": {
                            "path":"doc.partes.algo",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        { "term": { "doc.partes.algo.CUI": "C3244317" }},
                                        { "term": { "doc.partes.algo.CUI": "C2926602" }}
                                    ]

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I haven't got any results:

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

I've got results with *should* instead of *must*, but it's not the behaviour I've been searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) drops most punctuation, breaks up text into individual words, and lower cases them.

So probably C3244317 is indexed as c3244317, i.e., with lowercase 'c'.

You don't need such a large query. This should work fine:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "doc.partes.algo.CUI":"c3244317"
               }
            },
            {  
               "term":{  
                  "doc.partes.algo.CUI":"c2926602"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked!. The strangest thing is that with "should" worked in uppercase.

Comment: the standard analyzer should execute both in query and index time, so it shouldn't be responsible for the diference. Must implies that both clauses should be correct (logical AND), and should that only one should match (logical OR). You can use elasticsearch explain api to see whats happening.